# Isn't the way posts are displayed very unefficient?

Tags: posts, functions, design

I'm pretty much a WP newbie, and I've noticed that in a lot of themes, there is the exact same code for displaying posts in three different places (single.php, archive.php, index.php etc)

This just bugs me. It doesn't seem right to me, a programmer always trying to code as efficiently as possible.

What is the best way to generalize the layout for posts, preferably as a WordPress integrated/native function?

Comment: inefficient in what sense? number of lines or ease in which one is able to maintain and modify it?

Comment: Mainly the latter, and for me it seems like these kinds of things just should be templated anyway, why type (copy) it out thrice?

Comment: look into the themes Twenty Ten and Twenty Eleven, how these use `get_template_part()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could move the loop content into its own file and share that between the different template files using get_template_part()

Comment: Yep, this turned out to be what I was looking for. Thanks :)